# Getting sh: pvdisplay: command not found after upgrading to chef client 16

Tags: chef-infra

Recently we upgraded chef-client from 12.8.1 to 16.1.16..
After upgrading chef-client from 12.8.1 to 16.1.16, getting below error..
To test,i reverted chef-client back to 12.8.1 and deployment works fine with 12.8.1.
Are there any code-refactoring i'm missing that need to be done to upgrade to chef 16.1.16 version.

```
20:14:26   * execute[pvcreate] action run[2020-09-09T10:44:26-04:00] INFO: Processing execute[pvcreate] action run (ReportTomcat::default line 153)
20:14:26 [2020-09-09T10:44:26-04:00] INFO: Processing execute[Guard resource] action run (dynamically defined)
20:14:26 sh: pvdisplay: command not found
20:14:26 
20:14:26     [execute]   Can't initialize physical volume "/dev/sdc" of volume group "CSPD1VFPR02-ReportTomcat" without -ff
20:14:26                 /dev/sdc: physical volume not initialized.
20:14:26     
20:14:26     ================================================================================
20:14:26     [31mError executing action `run` on resource 'execute[pvcreate]'[0m
20:14:26     ================================================================================
20:14:26     
20:14:26     Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
20:14:26     ------------------------------------
20:14:26     Expected process to exit with [0], but received '5'
20:14:26     ---- Begin output of /sbin/pvcreate  /dev/sdc ----
20:14:26     STDOUT: 
20:14:26     STDERR: Can't initialize physical volume "/dev/sdc" of volume group "CSPD1VFPR02-ReportTomcat" without -ff
20:14:26       /dev/sdc: physical volume not initialized.
20:14:26     ---- End output of /sbin/pvcreate  /dev/sdc ----
20:14:26     Ran /sbin/pvcreate  /dev/sdc returned 5
20:14:26     
20:14:26     Resource Declaration:
20:14:26     ---------------------
20:14:26     # In /etc/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/ReportTomcat/recipes/default.rb
20:14:26     
20:14:26     153:   execute "pvcreate" do
20:14:26     154:      command "/sbin/pvcreate  #{ node['il']['ReportTomcat']['pvcreate']['drive']}"
20:14:26     155:      not_if "pvdisplay | grep  #{ node['il']['ReportTomcat']['pvcreate']['drive']}"
20:14:26     156:   end
20:14:26     157: 
20:14:26     
20:14:26     Compiled Resource:
20:14:26     ------------------
20:14:26     # Declared in /etc/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/ReportTomcat/recipes/default.rb:153:in `from_file'
20:14:26     
20:14:26     execute("pvcreate") do
20:14:26       action [:run]
20:14:26       default_guard_interpreter :execute
20:14:26       command "/sbin/pvcreate  /dev/sdc"
20:14:26       backup 5
20:14:26       declared_type :execute
20:14:26       cookbook_name "ReportTomcat"
20:14:26       recipe_name "default"
20:14:26       domain nil
20:14:26       user nil
20:14:26       not_if "pvdisplay | grep  /dev/sdc"
20:14:26     end
```

In other deployment, getting below error.

```
20:43:27     [execute] dzdo: sysctl: command not found
20:43:27               dzdo: sysctl: command not found
20:43:27     
20:43:27     ================================================================================
20:43:27     [31mError executing action `run` on resource 'bash[extract_module]'[0m
20:43:27     ================================================================================
20:43:27     
20:43:27     Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
20:43:27     ------------------------------------
20:43:27     Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
20:43:27     ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20200909-22973-7ommnx" ----
20:43:27     STDOUT: 
20:43:27     STDERR: dzdo: sysctl: command not found
20:43:27     dzdo: sysctl: command not found
20:43:27     ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20200909-22973-7ommnx" ----
20:43:27     Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20200909-22973-7ommnx" returned 1
20:43:27     
20:43:27     Resource Declaration:
20:43:27     ---------------------
20:43:27     # In /etc/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/il-content-middleware-service/recipes/contentmiddleware_service.rb
20:43:27     
20:43:27      59: bash 'extract_module' do
20:43:27      60:     code <<-EOH
20:43:27      61:         sudo sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=1024
20:43:27      62:         sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=4096
20:43:27      63:     EOH
20:43:27      64: end
20:43:27      65:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is occurring because a new property was added in Chef 14.2 to the [execute](https://docs.chef.io/resources/execute/) resource.

> `default_env`
>
> Ruby Type: true, false | Default Value: false
>
> When true this enables ENV magic to add path_sanity to the PATH and force the locale to English+UTF-8 for parsing output
>
> New in Chef Client 14.2

This is why `/sbin/pvcreate` was run (though it failed), but not `pvdisplay`.

There is further explanation for this on [client.rb](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client/) configuration.

> `enforce_path_sanity`
>
> Turn on path sanity in resources that shellout so that expected paths like /sbin or /bin are added to the PATH. Disabled by default.

You could fix it in different ways:

1. Use absolute path for commands in your execute/bash resource. Example:

   ```rb
   not_if "/sbin/pvdisplay | grep #{node['il']['ReportTomcat']['pvcreate']['drive']}"
   ```

   ```
   sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=1024
   ```
2. Add `default_env true` to your execute resource. Example:

   ```rb
   execute 'pvcreate' do
     command "pvcreate #{node['il']['ReportTomcat']['pvcreate']['drive']}"
     default_env true
     not_if "pvdisplay | grep #{node['il']['ReportTomcat']['pvcreate']['drive']}"
   end
   ```
3. Enable `enforce_path_sanity` in `client.rb`, this will be effective for all Chef resources that `ShellOut`. Example:

   ```rb
   enforce_path_sanity true
   ```

Comment: Thanks Seshadri for the quick help

Answer (score 0):

`enforce_path_sanity` was replaced with `enforce_default_paths`. There is an open issue on the [github](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/10201) for chef.